# How can I get a sum total from a field that is part of a dynamic row add?

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have a form, and the user can add as many rows as they want. One of the fields in the dynamic row is total cost. I am trying to figure out how to add the entries for this one particular field and display them on the following page.

I am coding in html 5, coldfusion and javascript.

Here is my script that generates the dynamic row:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var counter = 1;
        $("#addmrow").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var newRow = 
                '<tr id="rtr_' + counter + '">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" id="Qty_' + counter + '" name="Qty_' + counter + '" size=3/></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" id="Sku_' + counter + '" name="Sku_' + counter + '" size=10/></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" id="Description_' + counter + '" name="Description_' + counter + '" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" id="Retail_' + counter + '" name="Retail_' + counter + '" size=10/></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" id="TransferNumber_' + counter + '" name="TransferNumber_' + counter + '" size=10/></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" id="TransferDate_' + counter + '" name="TransferDate_' + counter + '" size=16/></td>' +
                '</tr>';
            counter++;
            $('#mlist').append(newRow);
        });
        $("#delmrow").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            counter--;
            $("#" + 'Qty_' + counter).remove();
            $("#" + 'Sku_' + counter).remove();
            $("#" + 'Description_' + counter).remove();
            $("#" + 'Retail_' + counter).remove();
            $("#" + 'TransferNumber_' + counter).remove();
            $("#" + 'TransferDate_' + counter).remove();
            $("#" + 'rtr_' + counter).remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my code displaying it on the next page, but I cant figure out how to add the Average Cost field so I get a sum total of that field:

```
                <cfloop index="i" list="#form.FieldNames#" delimiters=",">
                <cfif REFind("QTY_", i)>
                   <tr><td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif>
                <cfif REFind("SKU_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif> 
                <cfif REFind("DESCRIPTION_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif> 
                <cfif REFind("RETAIL_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif> 
                <cfif REFind("TRANSFERNUMBER_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif> 
                <cfif REFind("AVGCOST_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td></tr>
                </cfif> 
            </cfloop>
```

I hope I explained this correctly. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where in the html code is the cost field?

Comment: I have no idea of how coldfusion works but i get the gist of what you want, if you can work backwards from html put it into a fiddle and you'll open some doors, honestly. TIP, answerereres love jsFiddle/similar :).

Comment: you want the total via JavaScript or from your ColdFusion loop?

Comment: Start the next page by cfdumping your form scope.  See what fields come across when you sumbit the form with fields that were added dynamically.  That will help you to figure out what to do.

Comment: I actually am emailing the form results to myself, I just can't figure out how to do this in either javscript or coldfusion. Its sad I know, but I have been working on this for 2 days and cant figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are proably better ways to do this but given what you have this may be the simplest

```
            <cfset avgTotal = 0>           
            <cfloop index="i" list="#form.FieldNames#" delimiters=",">
                <cfif REFind("QTY_", i)>
                   <tr><td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif>
                <cfif REFind("SKU_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif> 
                <cfif REFind("DESCRIPTION_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif> 
                <cfif REFind("RETAIL_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif> 
                <cfif REFind("TRANSFERNUMBER_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td>
                </cfif> 
                <cfif REFind("AVGCOST_", i)>
                   <td><cfoutput>#form[i]#</cfoutput></td></tr>
                    <cfset avgTotal = avgTotal+form[i]> 
                </cfif> 
            </cfloop>
            <cfoutput>#avgTotal#</cfoutput>
```

Is that what you are tying to do?  Or have I completely missed the mark

Comment: I don't see a form field called avgcost anywhere in the part of the question that describes the form.

Comment: Lance, that is what I am trying to do. However when i use that logic, i get a 500 error saying "Variable AVGTOTAL is undefined. "

Comment: Dan, Yes, my apologies. Transfer Date was changed to Avg Cost, unfortunately I didnt post it after the change. Sorry.

Comment: AvgTotal id a variable I defined in the first line in the example